# Limit search results for ajax livesearch of images folder

Tags: php, ajax, image, search, livesearch

so I am trying to limit the amount of search results that show up when using ajax livesearch and I am not having any success. As of now the results are endless it seems and the files being used are 6-10mb pictures which sucks up a whole lot of memory and slows down the search tremendously. SO, I think the key is to limit search options (maybe 10 or 15 images) at this point. If anyone can show me how to do this I would be appreciative. Thx, any constructive criticisms are also welcome, if limiting the search is not the only way to improve speed and performance I would certainly like to hear it. Thx

```
function showResult(str) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("home").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("home").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("home").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("home").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","home.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I did some research and found this code on Stack that might be a fix for me but I dont know how to implement it properly, everytime i try it doesn't work:

```
$("#home").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(request.term);

        response(results.slice(0, 10));
    }
});
```

Here is my home.php code:

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("data.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('image'); //used to be link, now image, could be images

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];


if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {

    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('path');
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('thumbnail');
    $w=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('image');
    if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      //find a link matching the search text
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
           $hint="<a style='font: bold 16px/22px Georgia, serif;' href=' 
           ".$y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue."' target='_blank'>
           ".$y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue."
           ".$z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue." <br><br><br>
        ";
        }
      else
        {
         $hint=$hint ."<a style='font: bold 16px/22px Georgia, serif;' href=' 
         ".$y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue."' target='_blank'>
         ".$y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue."
         ".$z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue." <br><br><br>
        ";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


if ($hint=="") {
  $response="Search found ' 0 ' matches";
} else {
  $response=$hint;
}

echo $response;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For limit the search result listing only just replace this line in Home.php

for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++)

with

for($i=0; $i< NUMBER; $i++)

NUMBER is the amount of listing which you want to show.